# Duplicating class behaviour to second class (twitter bootstrap)

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter-bootstrap currently looks for the `active` class on an `li` element when working out which navigation element to highlight.

I'm using django-cms which defaults to using a `selected` class to indicate the same thing (i.e. "this tab is where you currently are"). Is there any way to do something like:

```
class "selected" = class "active"
```

The `li` element being generated by django-cms is done by the template tag `show_menu`, so I don't have immediate access to the element to add the `active` class myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hosting your own copy of Twitter Bootstrap (rather than hot-linking from Github) then you could change the Bootstrap `.active` class selector to

```
.active, .selected {
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, another option could be to use [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/). This can either be run client or server side and supports the type of inheritance you are looking for

```
.selected {
    .active;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can specify multiple css classes for your elements to use ...

```html
<div class="selected active">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `li` element getting rendered with the `selected` class is created behind the scenes (so to speak) by a django-cms template tag, not sure there's an easy way to add the additional class on the `li` element. I should have included this on the question.

Comment: if you're able to use jquery, you could find all elements with the "selected" class and add the "active" class to them.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the bootstrap mixin to look for "selected" instead of "active" - it beats cluttering your markup with unnecessary classes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to duplicate a class, all you have to do is create your own class and apply all the styles you want along with the `.active` class, e.g.

```
.pagination a:hover, .pagination .active a,  .pagination .selected a {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.pagination .active a, .pagination .selected a {
  color: #999999;
  cursor: default;
}
```

This way, the `.selected` class will apply all styles from the `.active` class as well.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found, is to specify a custom menu template in show_menu

```
{% show_menu 0 100 0 0 "bootstrap_menu.html" %}
```

And for bootstrap_menu.html you can take the original django-cms menu-template, copy it, and make sure it creates the 'active" class too:

```
{% load menu_tags %}
{% for child in children %}
    <li class="{% if child.selected %}selected active{% endif %}{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}{% if child.sibling %}sibling{% endif %}{% if child.descendant %}descendant{% endif %}">
        <a href="{{ child.attr.redirect_url|default:child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
        {% if child.children %}
            <ul>
                {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

You can find the django-cms menu template under ../menues/templates/menu in site packages if you installed using pip/easy_install/etc ..